# Changing a graph to list of nodes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I have these data types :

```
data Node a = Node
    { label :: a,
        adjacent :: [(a,Int)] } deriving Show
data Network a = Graph [Node a] deriving Show
```

I want to turn a graph to a list of nodes. For example I want to turn this :

```
Graph [ ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) , ( Node 'b' [ ('c' , 3 ) ] ) , ( Node 'c' [] ) ]
```

to this :

```
[ ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) , ( Node 'b' [ ('c' , 3 ) ] ) , ( Node 'c' [] ) ]
```

I wrote this function and some other variations of it :

```
deGraph Graph [Node x y] = [Node x y]
```

but I kept getting erros. Can you tell me how I should change my function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how to pattern match on a list.

```
foo [x] = x
```

matches a list of a single element and binds that element to x.

Since you want it to match on all lists, you'd do something like

```
foo xs = xs
```

so your code should change to

```
deGraph (Graph nodes) = nodes
-- Notice the fact that I wrapped the constructor
-- in parens
```

Wrap up:

Just to be explicit, here are the different ways you can match on a list

```
 -- matches on individual elements (this is syntactic sugary goodness)
foo [x, y] = x
 -- grabs the head and tail of the list (This is actual deconstructing)
foo (x:rest) = x
 -- matches an empty list
foo []       = error "Oh noes"
 -- matches everything
foo xs       = head xs
```

Or any combination of the above.

Comment: thank you for your respond. I already tried `deGraph (Graph nodes) = nodes` and it gave me this error : 
Main> deGraph [ ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) , ( Node 'b' [ ('c' , 3 ) ] ) , ( Node 'c' [] ) ]
**ERROR - Type error in application
 Expression     : deGraph [Node 'a' [('b',3),('c',2)],Node 'b' [('c',3)],Node 'c' []] 
Term           : [Node 'a' [('b',3),('c',2)],Node 'b' [('c',3)],Node 'c' []]
 Type           : [Node Char]
 Does not match : Network a**

Comment: That's because you forgot to wrap in the `Graph` constructor, you just passed in a raw list of `Node`s there

Comment: now it gave this :
Main> deGraph Graph [ ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) , ( Node 'b' [ ('c' , 3 ) ] ) , ( Node 'c' [] ) ]
ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : deGraph Graph [Node 'a' [('b',3),('c',2)],Node 'b' [('c',3)],Node 'c' []]
*** Term           : deGraph
*** Type           : Network d -> [Node d]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c

Comment: You need to make sure your precedence is right, you need parens around the constructor call

Comment: Can you explain what you said last a little bit more please?

Comment: It's currently parsing your expression as `(deGraph Graph) ...` which is incorrect, you want to use explicit parens `deGraph (Graph ...)`

Comment: I tried this : `deGraph (Graph [(Node x y)]) = [(Node x y)]` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you actually use `=`? It should be `==` but that won't work either since you didn't derive `Eq` on your datatype. Just run `deGraph (Graph nodes)` and that'll work

Comment: I'm sorry but `deGraph (Graph nodes)` is not working. It gives the last error I posted.

Comment: It's working fine for me.. I suspect your error is in your list of nodes

Comment: so is `deGraph (Graph nodes) = nodes` literally working for you?

Comment: No...... `deGraph (Graph <type a list of nodes>) <hit enter>` is working. As i've said, using `=` is going to give you an error...