# Haskell - get nth element without "!!"

Tags: haskell

I need to get the nth element of a list but without using the `!!` operator. I am extremely new to haskell so I'd appreciate if you can answer in more detail and not just one line of code. This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
nthel:: Int -> [Int] -> Int
nthel n xs = 0
let xsxs = take n xs
nthel n xs = last xsxs
```

But I get: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)

Comment: `let xsxs = take n xs` - what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 13):

There's a lot that's a bit off here,

```
nthel :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
```

is technically correct, really we want

```
nthel :: Int -> [a] -> a
```

So we can use this on lists of anything (Optional)

```
nthel n xs = 0
```

What you just said is "No matter what you give to `nthel` return 0". which is clearly wrong.

```
let xsxs = ...
```

This is just not legal haskell. `let ... in ...` is an expression, it can't be used toplevel.

From there I'm not really sure what that's supposed to do.

Maybe this will help put you on the right track

```
nthelem n [] = <???> -- error case, empty list
nthelem 0 xs = head xs
nthelem n xs = <???> -- recursive case
```

Try filling in the `<???>` with your best guess and I'm happy to help from there.

Alternatively you can use Haskell's "pattern matching" syntax. I explain how you can do this with lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936587/784338).

That changes our above to

```
nthelem n [] = <???> -- error case, empty list
nthelem 0 (x:xs) = x --bind x to the first element, xs to the rest of the list
nthelem n (x:xs) = <???> -- recursive case
```

Doing this is handy since it negates the need to use explicit `head` and `tail`s.

Comment: "From there I'm not really sure what that's supposed to do."

I'm trying to cut the list till the nth element and then take the last one (i.e. nth element). I figured out this would be the easiest way to take the nth element without !!. If you know something simpler feel free to share it. Anyways, thanks for the response!

Comment: I did, that's what the whole bottom of the post is

Comment: That's what I'm stuggling with - how to put both take and last in the <???>. Sorry for the dumb questions but I'm doing haskell for couple of hours.

Comment: You don't need `take` and `last`, you can do this just using recursion and `head` and `tail`. And dont worry about asking question, haskell is hard at first

Comment: I thought of recursion but what I struggle with is implementing two functions (head and tail) at once. I've only used on at a time untill now and I am not sure about the syntax.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't it be the same using head and tail and take and last, just the other way around? I mean in both cases, you take part of the text and then a certain element of this part?

Comment: Here, I'll fill in one for you, see if that helps

Comment: And to apply a function to the tail of a list do `func (tail list)`

Comment: advising `head` and `tail` and pattern matching on anything instead of `x:xs` = -1

Comment: @PhilipJF He's started haskell "A few hours ago" I'm not going to teach him something he can't understand. He doesn't even understand the syntax of functions, you want me to use pattern matching? Plus it makes the blanks completely trivial

Comment: well, pattern matching is pretty fundemental, and I don't think that `nthelem 0 (x:xs) = x` is much harder to read than what you have ( `nthelem n (x:xs) = nthelem (n-1) xs` as the final case).  I think we should teach pattern matching before `head` and `tail`.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, but it's not worth arguing over 2 rep :) I've edited to include pattern matching though

Answer (score 9):

I think you meant this:

```
nthel n xs = last xsxs
  where xsxs = take n xs
```

... which you can simplify as:

```
nthel n xs = last (take n xs)
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you! Both of you, vote yourself up cause my rating is too low to do it myself. :)

Comment: This only works if the list is at least as long as the desired index as take returns up to n or length of list so nthel 15 of "abc" returns 'c' instead of Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid using `last` whenever possible - lists are made to be used from the "front end", not from the back. What you want is to get rid of the first n elements, and then get the head of the remaining list (of course you get an error if the rest is empty). You can express this quite directly as:

```
nthel n xs = head (drop n xs)
```

Or shorter:

```
nthel n = head . drop n
```

Or slightly crazy:

```
nthel = (head .) . drop
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know list aren't naturally indexed, but it can be overcome using a common tips.

Try into ghci, `zip [0..] "hello"`, What's about `zip [0,1,2] "hello"` or `zip [0..10] "hello"` ?
Starting from this observation, we can now easily obtain a way to index our list.
Moreover is a good illustration of the use of laziness, a good hint for your learning process.

Then based on this and using pattern matching we can provide an efficient algorithm.

1. Management of bounding cases (empty list, negative index).
2. Replace the list by an indexed version using zipper.
3. Call an helper function design to process recursively our indexed list.

Now for the helper function, the list can't be empty then we can pattern match naively, and,

- if our index is equal to n we have a winner
- else, if our next element is empty it's over
- else, call the helper function with the next element.

Additional note, as our function can fail (empty list ...) it could be a good thing to wrap our result using Maybe type.

Putting this all together we end with.

```
nth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth n xs 
    | null xs || n < 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise        = helper n zs 
      where 
        zs = zip [0..] xs 
        helper n ((i,c):zs) 
            | i == n    = Just c
            | null zs   = Nothing
            | otherwise = helper n zs
```